# How to change the default styling of hyperlinks in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, formatting

I am working on converting my business's default Word templates to Google Docs. I have figured out how to change almost everything to look exactly the same as in Word except for being able to set the default styling of hyperlinks (to a green instead of the default blue). How can I do this?

Comment: It's not, i've already looked at that item. That explains nothing about hyperlinks and doesn't change their stylling - i've tried it already. Thanks for your comment @Alex

Comment: Have you tried styling "heading 6" towards the hyperlink style you want? I think it is a duplicate question. The duplicate suggestion, seems to be a duplicate.....

Comment: I saw the "Heading 6" Idea before, it doesn't work, as as soon as gdocs recognises the hyperlink it styles it back to blue again. Also, styling the html & css of the page isn't really what i'm looking to do as it will be exported to a PDF where styles won't be retained. I have done extensive research on this, I haven't found an answer to this anywhere before on stack exchange or anywhere else @JacobJanTuinstra

Comment: You are correct. I tried it myself before and again just now. The style saved, is indeed overruled. Thanks for persisting (+1)!!